# Please help Import-SPWeb Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am getting error when importing a publishing site. from production to my development server.

following is the error.

> Import-SPWeb : Requested value 'PublishingPages' was not found. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Import-SPWeb -Identity `http://spdev/departments/pmo` -Path E:\Backups\export-spwe ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletImportWeb:SPCmdletImportWeb) [Import-SPW
>   eb], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletImportWeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you a trying to import a web and not a whole sitecollection you need to check if your sitecollection where you want to import that web has "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" Feature ist activated.

This feature deploys the "PublishingPages" which you need.

Same problem also is described here: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6850cc40-45d2-4007-9a69-7a9cf464c60d/sharepoint-error-when-importing-web-requested-value-publishingpages-was-not-found?forum=sharepointadmin

Also check this one please:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/54ed4f8b-0bac-419e-af5b-40a71fa441b7/requested-value-publishingpages-was-not-found?forum=sharepointadmin

(cited from the link above)

> Before you import the cmp data, you need to create a subsite using the same template with the cmp data firstly.
>
> Per my knowledge, in SharePoint 2013, if you want to copy the site across farms, you need to make sure the source farm and target farm have same build number. So, for your environment, I suggest you upgrate the target farm to the same builder number with the source farm, then import the site again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's not enough for **Publising** features to be enabled.
**Deployment Manifest** generated from **Export-SPWeb** uses string value "**PublisingPages**" (15.0.4797.1001) for **[BaseTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb266223.aspx)** of **Pages** Library. There are cases when Import can't find template from that string value (15.0.4571.1502):

> [**List**] [**Pages**] **Error**: Requested value '**PublishingPages**' was not found.
>
> [**List**] [**Pages**] **Debug**:    at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)
>      at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, ISurrogateSelector selector)

In such case you can replace it with integer. You can find that integer in **Publising** feature definition in **hive**.

So to resolve this problem you can take this steps:

Rename .cmp file into .cab. Unpack it, find file manifest.xml, find **DocumentLibrary** node in it, replace attribute **BaseTemplate** from "**PublishingPages**" to "**850**", [pack files back](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#case2) into .cab then **Import-SPWeb** new file.